# Error compiling OpenZeppelin imported contracts

Tags: contract-development, compilation, import, truffle-compile, truffle-develop

I'm running a truffle project and have imported OpenZeppelin contracts.

While running truffle compile I'm facing following error:

```
github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol:4:1: 
ParserError: Source "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol" not found: 
File import callback not supported 
import "../math/SafeMath.sol"; 
^----------------------------^
```

How can I work around this issue?

It will be great if someone could help me understand what this error says.

Comment: Did you npm install the open zep contracts?

Comment: No I didn't do that. I downloaded the zip file and placed it in the project dir. Did I missed something?

Comment: Follow instructions here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/openzeppelin-solidity

Answer (score 2):

the question is old but I'll answer it anyway,

if you use VS Code add

```
 "solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesContractsDirectory": "",
 "solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesDirectory": "node_modules"
```

in it's settings.json